# Can't access page I created in React + Next.js App with App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am just starting to develop a web app using React and Next.js. I created the app by running the command `npx create-next-app`. Next, I added a new webpage `my-new-page.tsx` in the same directory as the app's homepage `page.tsx`.

**Note that this app uses [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes) not Pages Router.**

(You can see this app at github.com/thomzi12/app-with-new-page)

When I run `npm run dev` I can see `page.tsx` rendered at `http://localhost:3000/`. Makes sense.

However, when I go to `http://localhost:3000/my-new-page` ... I get a 404.

How do I access the page I just created?

Some hypotheses:

- I need to add the new page to some configuration? But I don't see page.tsx registered anywhere, so that's not the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a folder called `app-with-new-page` and inside you will need to add another `page.tsx`. You an learn more about Next.js's routing conventions and patterns in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing).

Comment: I am using App Router, not pages router. Here's the correct documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

Comment: @zthomas.nc You are aware that the link I have posted is for the app router and about routing fundamentals? Next to that my answer is completely valid. Rude behavior is not necessary.

Comment: Yeah you're right -- must have clicked on the link from the other answer and thought it was yours. Will reverse my downvote once I'm unfrozen, thanks!

Comment: Update: can't change my vote unless the answer is edited, but I went ahead and accepted it as correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Nextjs 13 with new app directory.

Nextjs 13 has folder baser routing. Each folder inside app directory acts a route (url) if it has page.tsx || (.js|.ts|.jsx).

In your case, create a folder in app directory with name `my-new-page` and inside this create your page component as page.tsx or page.jsx.

Now you can access this page at http://localhost:3000/my-new-page

Hope this helps.

You can message further if you still get issue

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer and then I'll reverse my downvote -- misread your response, my apologies

Comment: i provided more detailed explanation